# Program Loader and Runtime linker are the same?

Tags: linux, gcc, linker

Program Loader and Runtime linker are the same in linux?
I mean `ld-linux.so` acts as both loader during a program start time, and also as dynamic linker when `dlopen()` is called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Program Loader and Runtime linker are the same in linux?

Yes, they are. This is also true for every other [ELF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) platform.

Comment: Thanks. The program loader and run time linker could be different for any non-ELF platforms? Any examples?

Comment: On AIX, the program loader is part of the kernel, and the runtime linker is in a user-level library. http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/aix/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.aix.genprogc%2Fdoc%2Fgenprogc%2Fshared_object_runtime_linking.htm

Comment: Not exactly, see my reply. But they are related.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Your answer is incorrect. While `dlopen` in fact is contained in `libdl.so`, that library doesn't perform the *actual* work; instead it just calls on `ld-linux` to do that. In particular, `dl-runtime.c` that you referenced is linked into `ld-linux`, and not into `libdl`.

Comment: This is exactly what I said: dlopen inside libdl is just a wrapper or a glue to some code in ld-linux. The real work is done inside ld-linux, libdl is just some glue code.

Comment: On Linux the program loading is part of the kernel (`execve`) while loading is done by ld-linux.so (`man ld.so`). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26876247/how-does-execve-call-dynamic-linker-loader-ld-linux-so-2 I think this answer is not really correct and omits quite a lot of details about the loading of a program on Linux. Another answer about loaders on Linux can be found here: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/95740/92774

Answer (score 3):

I think there are very related, but not exactly the same.

The `/lib/libdl.so` (or `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2` on my system) library (containing `dlopen` and `dlsym`) is a sort of stub or glue code or wrapper using some part of `/lib/ld-linux.so.2` (or `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`) but it does not contain the same symbols, as you can check with `nm -D`.

Definitely `dlopen` and the dynamic loader do very similar things: [mmap](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap)-ing segments and interpreting relocation orders. See [this link](http://www.symantec.com/connect/articles/dynamic-linking-linux-and-windows-part-one) and [levine's linkers and loaders book](http://www.iecc.com/linker/)

Look into Gnu Libc source code like [dl-runtime.c](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob_plain;f=elf/dl-runtime.c) etc