# How does execve call dynamic linker/loader (ld-linux.so.2)

Tags: linux, linker, system-calls, execve

I used gcc to compile and link the most basic C program, test.c:

```
int
main() {
}
```

As expected, the output is a dynamically linked executable:

```
$ file test
test: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses     shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.26, BuildID[sha1]=0x0f806c099f74132a158d98aebde4639ae0998971, not stripped
```

Running strace gives the following output:

```
$ strace -f ./test
execve("./test", ["./test"], [/* 31 vars */]) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x248d000
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f77eeb27000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY)      = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=109292, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 109292, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f77eeb0c000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\300\357\1\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1595408, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 3709016, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f77ee580000
mprotect(0x7f77ee700000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f77ee900000, 20480, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x180000) = 0x7f77ee900000
mmap(0x7f77ee905000, 18520, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f77ee905000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f77eeb0b000
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f77eeb0a000
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f77eeb09000
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7f77eeb0a700) = 0
mprotect(0x7f77ee900000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f77eeb29000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7f77eeb0c000, 109292)          = 0
exit_group(-292524312)                  = ?
```

I was expecting to see "/lib64/ld-linux.so.2" somewhere in the strace output since according to the execve manual:

> If the executable is a dynamically linked ELF  executable,  the  interpreter  named  in  >the PT_INTERP  segment  is  used to load the needed shared libraries.  This interpreter >is typically /lib/ld-linux.so.2 for binaries linked with glibc 2

My guess is that the linker/loader (/lib64/ld-linux.so.2) call is part of execve. Can someone confirm?

Comment: Related: [\`bash: ./a.out: No such file or directory\` on running executable produced by \`ld\`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33970159) - the default path used by `ld` is `/lib/ld64.so.1`, which doesn't exist on most modern distros, so `gcc` should be passing a path that's correct for your system.  My answer there shows which tools are useful to examine the situation (`file` and `readelf`)

Answer (score 17):

> My guess is that the linker/loader (/lib64/ld-linux.so.2) call is part of execve.

This is somewhat correct.

The kernel first looks at the main executable segments, and `mmap`s them into the new "process shell".

When it discovers that the executable has `PT_INTERP` segment, it `mmap`s that file's segments as well, and passes control to *it*.

Thus, upon "return" from `execve()` into user-mode, the interpreter (usually `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` on Linux/x86_64) is already mapped in and running. It is then the job of that interpreter to relocate itself, to `mmap` the rest of required shared libraries, initialize them, and finally transfer control to the main executable.

If you want more details, start [here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.10.5/source/fs/binfmt_elf.c#L820).

Comment: The link you point to is broken. Could you provide a working link please? I know the answer is quite old, but I'm quite interested in learning more. Thanks

Comment: Thank you very much!