# Any user mode code runs before invoking default entry point of ELF?

Tags: linker, loader, elf

Many documents say program entry point (`_start` as default) does initialization like prepare command line, etc. How is the control been past to `_start` and any user-mode code was run before this for the new process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How is the control been past to _start and any user-mode code was run before this for the new process?

There are two cases to consider: a fully static, and a dynamically linked executable.

In the fully static case, the instruction at `_start` is very first user-mode instruction that is executed, i.e. the process is born with instruction pointer set at that instruction by the kernel.

In the dynamically linked case, the picture is much more complicated, and there are 1000s of user-mode instructions that run long before `_start`: the dynamic linker initializes itself, `mmap`s all required shared libraries, initializes them, and only then passes control to `_start`.

On glibc-based systems, you can observe this by running e.g.

```
LD_DEBUG=files /bin/date
```

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26903521/50617).